# For a left navigation panel with Ajax, should I use HTML frames or a DIV?

Tags: ajax, html, navigation, frame

I was going to have a left navigation panel which uses an ajax request to change the contents of the center panel of the HTML.

Should I use HTML frames or simply a "sidebar" DIV? Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A div.  You should pretty much never use frames.  Doing so causes problems, which [others have described](http://www.html-faq.com/htmlframes/?framesareevil).

Answer (score 2):

Many people argue against using frames: http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=html+frame+problems

Answer (score 2):

You should never use frames. That is very bad usability.
See "[Avoid using frames](http://universalusability.com/access_by_design/frames/avoid.html)" and [Why Frames Suck (Most of the Time)](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9612.html)

Load the content and bind it to the div. That's the best solution for dynamically updating a page.

[jQuer.load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)
[jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Post)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ajax, then an IFRAME makes no sense. On the other hand, using an iframe lets your user go back/forward between the pages he's visiting. But I don't understand what are your thoughts about linking together Ajax and an IFRAME. Google does this exactly for the purpose I mentioned a few lines above, to allow users to go backwards (no forward), but I don't know how they've implemented it.

Comment: I thought an iframe was different from a frame? Are we talking about he same thing?

Comment: IFRAMEs or FRAMEs are basically the same in this scenario. Why would you want to use frames in combination with Ajax? Isn't it a little more complicated than having a single page in which the actions on the navbar update the contents of an element in the same page? But as I said, pay attention to the functionality. I know some developers that have done an entirely Ajax-based admin system. In the end the owner hated it so much that she had to rewrite it. She really needed the Back button.

Comment: really simple history, on google code. look it up.  it does exactly as you've described w/ ajax and iframes.

Comment: @Ape-inago, old good HTTP does the same too, without all the hassle. Anyway, depends on the needs.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches have drawbacks. Leaving the problems that are common to both aside for the moment:

- Using frames gives you orphan pages.
- Using Ajax means that it requires JavaScript support and locks out search engines from the content (except for the front page) entirely. It breaks the back button.

There [are reasons](http://allmyfaqs.net/faq.pl?Problems_with_using_frames) why almost every side that implements common content on mutiple views just includes duplicates of the common content on every page.